# Hydra HTTP Form Post with parameters containing a colon ":"

Tags: brute-force, hydra

I'm trying to brute force login on my domain using THC Hydra v9.1-dev. It is using an `ASP.net` form and some of the required post body parameters contain a colon `:` in them which is the separator used by Hydra. An example parameter: `_ctl0:PlaceHolder:LoginName:txtLoginUsername=^USER^`.

This makes hydra think that I have `_ctl0` as the first part and `Placeholder` as the error message.

I tried:

- `URL encoding` them, e.g this becomes: `_ctl0%3APlaceHolder%3ALoginName%3AtxtLoginUsername=^USER^`
- placing the parameter in quotation marks `""`

but none of them worked and I can't seem to find a way to change the separator.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: colons should be escaped with backslashes `\`